# Do partial lockdown/social-distancing measures lead to more contagious and more deadly (Covid) virus mutations?

Tags: covid-19, virus

Reduction in social contact, without full restriction of social contact, creates an environment where the 'success' of a virus depends more on how infectious it is and less on how good it is at preserving the host.

Is this a fair assessment? Do these "lockdown"* measures result in more contagious strains? (*lockdown is a loose term it seems - what I mean are the restrictions where society is asked to do things like wear masks, avoid only certain types of shops, not others, etc).

I cannot easily find any research assessing the relationship between these lockdown measure, their level of implementation, and virus contagion/mortality.

If so, does this evolutionary pressure on the virus lead to more deadly strains? (Because, presumably, the criteria becomes more about contagion and rapid spread and less about preserving the host)

Is this what is happening as a result of social distancing policy today and is it something epidemiologists weigh up against the risks to the healthcare system of a freer policies?

EDIT/UPDATE: I realise that the downvotes are largely due to the way I posed the question and that there is a lot of political sensitivity here. Let me please assure you that my intentions are merely to find research and understand the real effect of lockdown. With no political bias. So to clarify:

I agree that successful isolation will cause the virus to die off. However, looking at society as a whole rather than at individuals, is it safe to say that the practical reality of lockdown is that face masks are worn incorrectly, with incorrect materials, for extended lengths of time beyond their applicability, that people don't fully self isolate but just to a certain extent, etc etc. It still seems to me the virus is given opportunities to replicate but only if they acclimatize to the tougher conditions. Is there any research around to refute or understand this claim?

Comment: For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Have you read anything which even partially backs your theory? Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thank you for your polite response. Unfortunately, I have tried, and I do not see very much. In fact, epidemiological advice and rhetoric seems to be quite politicised. For example, people talk about comorbidities without really acknowledging that the obesity-related comorbidity correlation with covid could well be visceral ACE receptor site prevalence in the overweight. Technical discussions behind the scenes might be more matter of fact, but what is available publically seems to be quite watered down.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I should also add, I am not looking for anything necessarily that backups the implied theory, but also anything that falsifies it.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Actually, I have looked again and can find literally nothing on lockdown effect on virus transmissibility/mortality.

Comment: @Fizz Sorry if the way i phrased the question offended you. I know in the USA it's all very poltical and a very touchy subject, but let me assure you I am genuinely interested in understanding what would seem intuitive to me, without any political bias.

Comment: You last/edited point, regarding partial measures may be somewhat valid, e.g. some epidemiologists fear that an incorrect roll-out of two phase vaccines, wihth too long of an interval between the doses may select virus strains for increased antigenic drift (i.e. more capable of escaping some immune responses). It's not clear how much of that thinking can be applied to "partially worn masks" though, which isn't exactly what is meant by "lockdown" anyway. So you're kinda shifting the goal posts here. The question about partial masking may be a good one, but hard to quantify the effect.

Comment: @Fizz Accepted, yes, the word lockdown is too ambiguous. Over here where I live they are using the phrase lockdown to mean anything really, with varying degrees. I will update the question.

Comment: @Fizz In fact I should probably bin this question and start again, it's getting messy.

Comment: Regarding the updated q: possibly of course, but partial adherence or on-off measures already have known bad effects in terms of disease spread. If on top of that they also produce (more) variants... sure it's a concern, but unlike antigenic drift in the presence of antibodies, the effects of partial adherence to measures is not something easy to measure in a test tube. And it's unclear why someone would spend money (i.e. give a grant) for something like this... or how would you test it... as naturally produced mutations/strains take time to appear and need a fairly large population.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot easily find any research assessing the relationship between lockdowns and virus contagion/mortality.

Try looking at it backwards: what encourages mutations (some of which will render an organism more *x* (and/or *y*, and/or *z*) and some of which will render it less *x* (and/or *y*, and/or *z*). To mutate, an organism must reproduce in order to pass on a mutation. Look at the [evolution of MRSA](https://blogs.biomedcentral.com/on-biology/2017/07/21/the-genesis-of-mrsa-resistance-emerged-years-before-the-introduction-of-methicillin-in-the-clinic/) as a good example: all that was needed was reproduction; environmental pressure selected the successful.

Understanding this fundamental concept sheds light on the confusion you have.

Simply stated, if lockdowns decrease the chances of viral replication (which they do very well), they will also decrease the chances of viral mutations, whether that be for a less contagious/lethal virus (not a good candidate for responding well to environmental pressure) or a more contagious/lethal one.

> Is this what is happening as a result of social distancing policy today and is it something epidemiologists weigh up against the risks to the healthcare system of a freer policies?

Nope, not at all. Because that's not how viruses become more successful.

Edited to add: Imagine a patient, J. Doe, early 60s, lives alone, leaves the house only to do monthly grocery shopping.  During one of these outings, J. becomes infected with SARS-CoV 2. Early in the course of infection, a mutation occurs which increases the transmissibility of the virus by 50%. J., however, has mild symptoms only, and during a teleconference with a physician, J. is told to stay home and treat symptomatically. J. follows this advice, the infection runs its course, and the viruses die off. J. has avoided all contact with others and the newer, more transmissible virus had no where (else) to go.

Now imagine J. Dope, early 60s, lives alone, doesn't like it, so goes out a lot despite warnings.  During one of these outings, J. becomes infected with SARS-CoV 2. Early in the course of infection, a mutation occurs which increases the transmissibility of the virus by 50%. J., however, has mild symptoms only, so doesn't alter social behaviors. J. sheds the newer, more transmissible virus everywhere, and suddenly, a spike in cases is seen in the area J. lives.

Which scenario is likely to increase the prevalence of the now more highly transmissible virus variant?

Comment: Thank you. I agree that successful isolation will cause the virus to die off. However, looking at society as a whole rather than at individuals, is it safe to say that the practical reality of lockdown is that face masks are worn incorrectly, with incorrect materials, for extended lengths of time beyond their applicability, that people don't fully self isolate but just to a certain extent, etc etc. It still seems to me the virus is given opportunities to replicate but only if they acclimatize to the tougher conditions. In other words, what research actually backs up your hypothesis?

Comment: In fact I think I will try to add the above comment into the original question.

Comment: I also know for example that in my local hospital, 50% of vaccinated health workers are now testing positive for the British mutation, and those hospital staff are being sent away from non-covid wards because they are considered infectious.

Comment: Although I upvoted this already, to go from thought experiment to at least *in silico* experiments with RNA models, larger populations generally result in higher mean fitness. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5666329/

Comment: @Frank: 50% failure rate on an approved vaccine would be amazing, so I'm calling BS on that or they were just vaccinated and immunity didn't kick in yet. The British/Kent strain has shown no [enhanced] ability to evade the approved vaccines (unlike the South African one). The (suspected) reason why the Kent strain (B.1.1.7) becomes dominant over the older ones is that infections with it last longer (13 vs 8 or so days), so it has more chance to spread; see https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00502-w (somewhere in the middle of the long page).

Comment: @Fizz Well that data was verbal from the hospital director in person.

Comment: @Frank - All of your first comment points were irrelevant to my answer, which was direct and addressed your point. If all you want to do is argue, I'm uninterested.

Comment: I also agree wit @Fizz regarding the claim that "50% of vaccinated health workers are now testing positive for the British mutation..." is questionable. It is you who should be providing reliable sources for your claims. "The director told me himself" is not a reliable source to make such a claim. It flies in the face of the data collected so far. To Frank: "what research actually backs up your hypothesis?" So far, all of it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am not convinced. Eg: the Kent mutation, under the influence of social distancing policy , is a virus that is both more contagious and more deadly. I want explicit links. And a less snooty, arrogant tone.

Comment: @Frank - "I want explicit links. And a less snooty, arrogant tone." That's a great example of irony.

Comment: @Fizz By the way - the actual hospital director was on video saying that vaccinated hospital staff are testing positive for the new strain and as part of the online town council video conference. The director was begging for tougher restrictions because the ICU wards are just about full. 2 days later we have military police around the nearby towns and full lockdown. My wife works in the hospital and also confirms the vaccinated (AstraZeneca) staff are testing c19 positive with the new strain and having to be rotated out of work and wards.

Comment: @Fizz - and the spike was rapid and recent, and another interesting thing is that the tpical age of patients in the last few weeks dropped to people in their 40s / 50s, with more younger patients. The recent spike was exponential - quite amazing really - hospital helicopters and ambulances racing past my house (which is 15km from the nearest hospital) 4 or 5 times a day.

Comment: @Fizz. So yeah. Definitiely not bullshit. Just not in line with the media narrative.

Comment: @Frank: it does look like the AZ vaccine produces lower titers against B 1.1.7 https://www.bioworld.com/articles/503277-positive-news-astrazeneca-vaccine-still-effective-in-b117-sars-cov-2-variant That would probably allow more infections, albeit with still reduced symptoms. Still, it's not really the topic of this q, but it could be a good separate one. (Pfizer claimed no difference for theirs: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.01.18.426984v1)

Comment: The Pfizer paper was actually published today https://science.sciencemag.org/content/371/6534/1152 The *Science* abstract says "slight but significant decrease in neutralization that was more apparent in participants under 55 years of age". The authors say "On the basis of experience from studying antibody correlates of disease protection for influenza virus vaccines, a 20% reduced titer does not indicate a biologically relevant change in neutralization activity."

Comment: @Fizz I have got like 2 people in my immediate circle of acquaintances in ICU now, and now quite a few with their 2nd covid infection (new mutation probably) and this time really, really ill . Repeated hospital visits. Avg age about 48 or so

Comment: @Frank - Personal experience does not trump data collected in a reliable manner. The Astra-Zeneca vaccine is less effective against the South Africa variant (and possibly others) which is why South Africa stopped using it. None of these asides change the truth that viruses mutate when they replicate, not wen selection pressure is reduced. As for snootiness, you may be mistaking precise speech with (?)elitism/superiority/snootiness. I write with precise speech (and some confidence wen I have it) because my profession is science: physician and molecular biologist. I can interpret the studies...

Comment: ...and have a very significant understanding of the science behind infectious diseases and pathogens because of decades of study and practice, and have an advantage over some of my contemporaries because I was a molecular biologist before I became a physician. But - *but* - I also studied logic, and will be the first  to tell you that an *argument from authority* (you can believe me because I'm [x]) is as fallacious as an *argument from personal experience*.  I've accurately explained the science in my answer. Your comments include several logical fallacies, including an *ad hominem*. (...)

Comment: ,,, Use of an ad hominem doesn't make your comments scientifically untrue.  Anyone having an idea might be correct without the rest of the world knowing it. [Barry Marshall](https://www.discovermagazine.com/health/the-doctor-who-drank-infectious-broth-gave-himself-an-ulcer-and-solved-a-medical-mystery) is one of my favorite heroes of medicine and humanity. I'm just pointing out why your comments are unconvincing. They do not change scientific fact, nor do they supplant sound data collection and documentation by those trained in the field.

Comment: Selection pressure drives "success" of viruses (see the MRSA link for a good example of selection pressure.) If a potentially *very* "successful" virus comes into existence in a closed space, it will not spread and fulfill its potential.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Your last comment is quite obviously true, but that is not really related to the thrust of my question. But that was because the question was poorly formulated. I asked again in a better way and have the answer I need. By the way, I would be interested to know if/what agent based models are used by scientists in that field? Clearly the problem is understanding how a complex, dynamic system behaves , so I would be surprised if any sweeping generalisation about the effects of social distancing measures apply very well.